# php setting values at parent level

Tags: php, oop

I have a `User` class extending an `Id` abstract class. Somehow I will introduce another class called `Event` extending the `Id` class too. The `__construct()` methods are very similar, so I want to put the constructor code in the `Id` class.

Here is my `__construct()` method:

```
class Event extends Id
{
    public function __construct($id, $object){
        $this->id = $id;
        foreach($object as $property => $value) {
            if (property_exists($this, $property)) $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}

class User extends Id
{
    public function __construct($id, $object){
        $this->id = $id;
        foreach($object as $property => $value) {
            if (property_exists($this, $property)) $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I put the method in the `Id` class, PHP warns me at `$this->$property = $value;`. It says that I have some attributes stated `private` in the `User` or `Event` class so that it cannot be initiated in `Id` class.

What I want is to reuse my code while keeping those variables `private` (because I do not want other except parent class to access them!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

- Use `protected` variables
- You could use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php) to cheat and set private variables.
- Use traits (5.4) to import a common `__construct`
- Refactor a bit. e.g., have a `setProperty` in the child classes that the parent calls, or implement `__set`, etc